# interfaces without implementation in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, interface, javabeans, dead-code

is there a quick way to find (may be by using intellij or maven etc) all the interfaces (java) without any implementation.

I need to do above as we did some clean up of code where we removed a number of classes (and corresponding interfaces) which we think are not in use, but there could be the possibility that some interfaces may be left to be removed (due to manual error as it was huge clean up) which may be used by a bean which may cause run time exception. I am doing manual validation but if some automate way is present then it will be great.

regards
Sanjay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to perform **(Analyze | Run Inspection by Name | Unsued declaration | [Choose the necessary filters](https://prnt.sc/sxs1as))**.
See the relevant [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-inspections.html) for more options.